# Как вырезать часть строки по символу Python

Tags: python

Есть такая строка:

```
[76561199220900000] was killed by LAZYBOY [76561199401710000] at (72.9, 27.7, 174.4)
```

Как можно её обрезать по символу "[" и "]", чтобы на выходе получилось значение между этих символов, т.е.:

```
76561199220903241 76561199401719396
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
import re
text = "[76561199220900000] was killed by LAZYBOY [76561199401710000] at (72.9, 27.7, 174.4)"
result = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', text)
print(result)
```

Если позиция частей строки в скобках не меняется в строке, то можно еще попробовать этот вариант:

```
text = "[76561199220900000] was killed by LAZYBOY [76561199401710000] at (72.9, 27.7, 174.4)"
text_arr = text.split()
first = text_arr[0][1:-1]
second = text_arr[5][1:-1]
print(first, second)
```

Comment: Благодарю. Всё работает.

Comment: @ПтицаСиница не за что, отметьте пожалуйста ответ как правильный, чтоб галочка появилась)